# (WinSock), What should I fill in WSARecvFrom source ip address for server?

Tags: udp, winsock

So, I'm implementing udp packet communication between client and server.

I've already done sending udp data to client from server using `WSASendTo`

For client side, the parameter `sockaddr* ipFrom` in `WSARecvFrom` is server's endpoint. Everything works good.

But the problem is that the server uses only one udp socket, so I don't know what should I fill in `sockaddr* ipFrom` parameter in `WSARecvFrom`. Since each client has different ip, I can't specify the source ip address.

I tried to just fill nullptr in this parameter but it didn't work. And I tried fill it with server endpoint, and it worked.

But as you know, using server endpoint for `ipFrom` doesn't make sense because that is not source address, so I'm curious what address/endpoint should I fill in `sockaddr* ipFrom`.

EDIT : By the way, I binded udp socket as server ip/port before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the problem is that the server uses only one udp socket, so I don't know what should I fill in `sockaddr* ipFrom` parameter in `WSARecvFrom`.

Nothing. That is not your responsibility to do in that call.

> But as you know, using server endpoint for `ipFrom` doesn't make sense because that is not source address, so I'm curious what address/endpoint should I fill in `sockaddr* ipFrom`.

None.

You seem to have a misunderstanding of what the `ipFrom` parameter is meant for. It is an **output** parameter, not an input parameter. So you don't need to supply any data to it at all. `WSARecvFrom()` *receives* an incoming packet. If you want to know who the sender of that packet is (ie, to send a subsequent reply back using `WSASendTo()`), you supply a pointer to an allocated `sockaddr_...` and then `WSARecvFrom()` fills it with the sender's info. You don't fill the `sockaddr_...` yourself at all.

Just like when the client receives a packet from the server and `WSARecvFrom()` reports the server's info, the same is true when the server receives a packet from a client and `WSARecvFrom()` reports the client's info.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you answer one more question? What can I do when two clients have same IP address? As far as I know, server knows only public IP address. How to separate these client's endpoint and send UDP packet to each client?

Comment: I searched for a while and I think I found the answer. So, If I bind client's udp socket port as zero, system automatically find appropriate port number so that all client behind NAT has unique port number. So, server just use that information and send udp packet back. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, each client will have a unique IP/port pair. Even if the IP is not unique, the port will be. Even if multiple clients use the same port behind the same NAT, the NAT is likely to map them to unique ports on its end. So, whatever `sockaddr_...` that `WSARecvFrom()` gives you, is the `sockaddr_...` that you have to send back to. It contains both the client's IP and port in it.